# C# I don't understand the code after the constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I don't understand the code after the constructor.

```
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseConfiguration(config)
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

from
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNETCoreWebsiteToACheapLinuxVMHost.aspx

Comment: They're just method calls, in a fluent format. Read the documentation or intellisense.

Comment: They're configuration calls using the fluent pattern.

Comment: They are method calls to configure the application (and especially the web hosting part). E.g. see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are [extension] methods of the `IWebHostBuilder` interface.

It is designed to be used as a fluent API, meaning each call to a method returns an instance of [presumably] the same object which implements the `IWebHostBuilder` interface, so you can keep calling methods on it in a chain.

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder() //This call would return IWebHostBuilder
.UseKestrel() //This call would return IWebHostBuilder
.UseConfiguration(config) //This call would return IWebHostBuilder
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) //This call would return IWebHostBuilder
.UseStartup<Startup>() //This call would return IWebHostBuilder
.Build(); //This call would return IWebHost
```

So in the end, the host variable is the result of several operations called on [presumably] the same object, culminating in the call to one final method, `Build`, which returns an object of type `IWebHost`.

This is functionally equivalent to:

```
var builder = new WebHostBuilder();
builder = builder.UseKestrel();
builder = builder.UseConfiguration(config);
builder = builder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
builder = builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
var host = builder.Build();
```

I say "presumably" because it all depends on the internal implementation.

Comment: @MartinLiversage: Nice catch. I updated the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

It's simply method chaining and is common in fluent design patterns (like LINQ etc).

For example:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass DoSomething()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

With the above you could then do:

```
var test = new TestClass().DoSomething();
```

In your example specifically it's used to configure the web host ready for use. In this case:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel() // Use Kestrel web server
    .UseConfiguration(config) // Use the IConfiguration specified in config
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) // Set the content directory
    .UseStartup<Startup>() // Set the startup class
    .Build(); // Build and instantiate an IWebHost based on the above configuration
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a class

```
public class C
{
    public C MethodA()
    {
        //TODO: do something useful here.
        return this;
    }

    public C MethodB()
    {
        //TODO: do something useful here.
        return this;
    }

    public C MethodC()
    {
        //TODO: do something useful here.
        return this;
    }
}
```

where the methods return an instance of the object itself, you can either call these methods like this:

```
var c = new C();
c.MethodA();
c.MethodB();
c.MethodC();
```

or

```
var c = new C();
c.MethodA().MethodB().MethodC();
```

or even

```
var c = new C().MethodA().MethodB().MethodC();
```

It is also possible that these calls return another object of possibly another type. In this case the statement `var result = new T().A().B().C();` is equivalent to:

```
var temp1 = new T();
var temp2 = temp1.A();
var temp3 = temp2.B();
var result = temp3.C();
```

The methods can be extension methods as well.

This is called [Method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) and is used in [Fluent interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand the code after the constructor.

I think you are confused by this only because its done on the constructor. Your code is equivalent to this:

```
    var builder = new WebHostBuilder();
    var host = builder.UseKestrel()
                      .UseConfiguration(config)
                      .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                      .UseStartup<Startup>()
                      .Build();
```

So there is no special magic in those method calls, it just happened to be called on the object that the `WebHostBuilder()` returned.